# Vue.js form submit doesn't work after hide and show a bootstrap panel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuex

I've 3 `bootstrap panels` that are shown depending on the value of the `select` that we choose:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <Select/>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" v-if="fileMode == 0"></div>
<div class="panel panel-default" v-else-if="fileMode == 1"></div>
<div class="panel panel-default" v-else>
 <div class="form" id="uploadCsvForm"/>
</div>
```

js:

```
  mounted() {
    var self = this;
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      $("#uploadCsvForm").submit(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         self.uploadCsvAndGetData();
         return true;
      });
    });
  },
```

So after hide and show the panel that has the form, the  `$("#uploadCsvForm").submit(function(e)` doesn't work anymore... 
Do you know why?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `div` is removed and the event handler binding is lost. Try not to mix Vue with jQuery. Something like this would be better:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <Select/>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" v-if="fileMode == 0"></div>
<div class="panel panel-default" v-else-if="fileMode == 1"></div>
<div class="panel panel-default" v-else>
 <div class="form" @submit="uploadCsvAndGetData"/>
</div>
```